# svg sprite in css - is transform scale legit way of scaling

Tags: html, css, svg

Im using SVG sprite as a CSS background image like this:

```
.icon-arrow-down-dims {
  background: url("../sprite/css-svg-sprite.svg") no-repeat;
  background-position: 16.666666666666668% 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

The only way I could scale that and that it works as expected is to use `transform: scale(2)` to make it 2 times bigger or `transform: scale(.5)` to make it two times smaller.

```
.icon-arrow-down-dims {
  @extend %svg-common;
  background-position: 16.666666666666668% 0;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

That really does scale it and it works because its not pixelated like png sprites. 
My question is: is that a legit way of scaling svg css sprite? Are there any other ways to achieve it? Thanks in advance

Comment: [list questions are not a good idea](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) If I listed out 3 ideas to do scaling and someone else listed 3 other ideas, which answer would you accept?

Comment: If it matters to you then yours, im really just trying to get help, is that like a wrong thing :)

Comment: It makes no difference to me which you accept. I'm just trying to get you to ask a better question. I.e. why does it matter to you what way you achieve your solution? What criteria are you going to use to determine what solution is the best one? What is "legit"? Given that your solution works for you what is not  "legit" about it?

Comment: Yea I agree my question needs more parameters. Well my solution is working but its not working great and i really dont think that is the best solution.

Comment: You have not explained why it's not "working great" though.

Comment: because when using it with pseudo it has bugs on transform

Comment: Then you'll need to create an [mcve] showing that.

Comment: Thanks for everything! Would you suggest opening a new issue or ?

Answer (score 1):

Why just not using width and height for scalling?

Your way of scaling is not wrong, but I am not sure if it will be compatible with every browser.

Here is an example.

```
.icon {
    background-size: auto 100% !important;
    display:inline-block;
}
.icon.small {
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
}
.icon.large {
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
}
.icon_1 {
    background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="16" viewBox="0 0 64 16"> <circle fill="blue" cx="8" cy="8" r="8"/> <circle fill="red" cx="24" cy="8" r="8"/> <circle fill="yellow" cx="40" cy="8" r="8"/> <circle fill="green" cx="56" cy="8" r="8"/> </svg>') 100% 0 no-repeat;
}
.icon_2 {
    background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="16" viewBox="0 0 64 16"> <circle fill="blue" cx="8" cy="8" r="8"/> <circle fill="red" cx="24" cy="8" r="8"/> <circle fill="yellow" cx="40" cy="8" r="8"/> <circle fill="green" cx="56" cy="8" r="8"/> </svg>') 33.33% 0 no-repeat;
}
```

**Edit**
The above example will not work if you dont specify viewBox. Thanks @RobertLongson

*The transform attribute defines a list of transform definitions that are applied to an element and the element's children*

Now look, transform = scale(2) will work great until you dont have  a children to that div element that has your svg, if you do have a child than it will be scaled too. However if you are using width and height, only the parent will be scaled.

Check this link >> for more examples https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/

Comment: If the image has viewBox="none" then setting a width/height won't scale it. This seems worse therefore than the OPs original idea.

Comment: So my idea is not great but better than this?

Comment: @RobertLongson you are right, svg needs a viewBox in order to be scaled.

Comment: @riogrande I could suggest various alternatives, you have provided no criteria for determining whether mine would be better or worse than yours so your question as stated is just a shopping list question.

Comment: I would love to know some alternatives because google is not giving me results i want

Answer (score 1):

This is legit. Transform is native SVG functionality and should always work fine with SVG elements.

If you need only one specific size for it to look nicely I suggest you to edit the SVG sprite code (it's XML looking exactly like HTML so you will have no problems understanding it), ensure all SVG elements are encapsuled in one group and add transform as an attribute to this group. This is basically like opening the sprite in a graphic editor, scaling it and saving.

If you have more questions about SVG ask away.

Comment: Great! Are there any more techniques of scaling css svg sprites? Some sites suggest something with background-size?

Comment: Sprite is a small part of whole background. If you mess around with background-size you can get unpredictable results like not having it positioned on a desired sprite. But if it works for you then just do it, how can I know if you haven't provided working example of your case.